# Angular docker image build using buildx failing

Tags: angular, docker, buildx

I'm trying to build the multi-arch docker image using buildx.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.1-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
#RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install

ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

COPY . ./

RUN ng build

FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**buildx cmd**

```
docker buildx build  --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --tag <some-tag> .
```

**Console errors**

```
#0 12.99 Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
#0 13.45 Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
#0 13.63 Compiling ngx-window-token : es2015 as esm2015
#0 13.74 Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
#0 13.75 Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
#0 13.80 Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.21 Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.23 Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.41 Compiling ngx-clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.59 Compiling @ngx-translate/core : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.79 Compiling ng-inline-svg : module as esm5
#0 14.91 Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
#0 14.94 Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
#0 15.05 Compiling ngx-webstorage : es2015 as esm2015
#0 15.46 Compiling ng-apexcharts : es2015 as esm2015
#0 15.68 Compiling ngx-perfect-scrollbar : es2015 as esm2015
#0 15.89 Compiling @ng-select/ng-select : es2015 as esm2015
#0 15.99 Compiling ngx-pagination : module as esm5
#0 16.44 Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
#0 16.53 Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
#0 17.14 - Generating browser application bundles...
#0 56.04 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
#0 57.65 - Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     COPY . ./
  11 |     
  12 | >>> RUN ng build
  13 |     
  14 |     FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ng build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 137
```

Comment: Exit code 137 is an out-of-memory error. Are you running Docker on Linux or on MacOS/Windows?

Comment: macbook pro m1  8gb ram

Comment: I ran that Dockerfile on a new angular project and didn't receive any errors, the image built fine.  My guess is it has something to do with your Angular project and not the Dockerfile.  If you run `ng build` on the project by itself outside of Docker, are there any errors?

Comment: try a `ng build --configuration=production` on your project check if it builds

Comment: Note that Docker on MacOS is running inside a Linux virtual machine. It's possible you will need to increase the amount of memory allocated to the Docker VM.